# Excel - create new definition of function based on results form other cell with complex formula

Tags: excel

Have two excel spreadsheets. In first excel is a lot of HEX decoded data (eg.73F57D5AA922166CA546318DA9B6E0EF),  in second excel is complex AES encoded solution (https://www.nayuki.io/page/aes-cipher-internals-in-excel) with little modify input by me (no need update ciphertext table, table get update from string - is alternative as original)

The problem is how make mass process by simple drag in excel?  No problem move decoded HEX data to 2nd spreadsheet but how connect it and mass process?

Best what I can imagine is create new function based on AES complex solution from 2nd excel and use the function where argument is HEX decoded data as input and result is encoded HEX string but how to do it?

[Here graphical how encode strings now, manual copy and paste between excels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Co3o.png)

Search and use other excel AES encode function but all what I found encode strings, not HEX strings (cannot adopt other AES encode function to my data), I have HEX in string data and mentioned excel solution encode correct data.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.